# Find $x_n$ such that $ \exp(- \sqrt{2 \log n} x_n - x_{n}^{2}/2) = (\sqrt{ 2 \log n} + x_n) \sqrt{2 \pi}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, logarithms

Consider the equation
$$
\exp(- \sqrt{2 \log n} x_n - x_{n}^{2}/2) = (\sqrt{ 2 \log n} + x_n) \sqrt{2 \pi}.
$$
What does it mean, that the leading terms for $x_n$ are given by
$$
x_n = - \frac{\log \log n+ \log 4 \pi}{2 \sqrt{2 \log n}}
$$
?